# da.fill incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: vb.net, syntax-error

I'm having a problem from the line

```
da.Fill(ds, "Employee")
```

and I don't have any clue to solve this. Can anyone help?

This is my actual code:

```
 Private Sub btnsearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsearch.Click
    Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable


    If txtssn.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please input SSN.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Company Records - Employee")
    Else
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Employee] WHERE [Ssn] = '" & Trim(Me.txtssn.Text) & "')", con)

        da.SelectCommand = cmd

        da.Fill(ds, "Employee")
        dt = ds.Tables("Employee")

        If (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
            Me.txtfname.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
            Me.txtmi.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(2)
            Me.txtlname.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(3)
            Me.dtpbdate.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(5)
            Me.txtaddress.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(6)
            Me.cmbsex.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(7)
            Me.txtsalary.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(8)
            Me.cmbsuperssn.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(9)
            'Me.cmbdept.Text =
            btnedit.Enabled = True
            btndelete.Enabled = True
            editable()

        Else
            MsgBox("Record Not Found", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Company Records - Employee")
        End If

        con.Close()
    End If
```

Comment: The devil in me says: Type `';DROP TABLE Employee;--` , but I prefer to say: Read about Sql Injection

Answer (score 2):

Remove the closing parantheses since that's a `SELECT` not an `INSERT`:

```
"SELECT * FROM [Employee] WHERE [Ssn] = '" & Trim(Me.txtssn.Text) & "'"
```

However, i would always use sql-parameters to prevent sql-injection.

```
Using con As New SqlConnection("ConenctionString")
    Using da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Employee] WHERE [Ssn] = @SSN", con)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@SSN", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtssn.Text
        da.Fill(ds, "Employee")
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the trailing `)` from your SQL statement.

```
"SELECT * FROM [Employee] WHERE [Ssn] = '" & Trim(Me.txtssn.Text) & "'"
```

Also see why you [shouldn't be doing it in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683).

Answer (score 1):

Their is syntax error near your `SQL`statement so you need to remove an unwanted `(` to make this statement workable.

```
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Employee] WHERE [Ssn] = '" & Trim(Me.txtssn.Text) & "'", con)
```